# What is best way to setup your Tracing in Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, trace, production, otel

I want to collect traces from my applications to better know what fixes and tweaks do they need. What is the best way to setup my tracing to get all necessary info? I was thinking about adding span to all beans and its public methods in IoC container which are being used. Is it correct to use tracing this way? In this case I would have a lot of info about time consuming methods with different scenarios.

Comment: Try to learn about Spring boot actuator:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html

Comment: Hey! Indeed that is library which i am using. Based from references i can put annotation "@Observed" (from micrometer library) on whatever i like - to put span in my trace. My question was more oriented towards whether is good or bad idea to use @Observed on every business logic oriented piece of code in my app.